# Mean of gamma distribution.

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

So I was trying to prove the mean result of gamma distribution which is $\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$.

My attempt,

$E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty }x f(x)dx$

$=\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{\lambda^{\alpha}}{\Gamma (\alpha)}x^{\alpha}e^{-\lambda x}dx$

After integrating it, I got the result $$\frac{\lambda^{\alpha}}{\Gamma (\alpha)} \cdot\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}(\int_{0}^{\infty } x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}dx)$$. I'm stuck here. Could anyone continue it for me and explain? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use the substitution $\lambda x=t $ Then the definition of the Gamma function.

Comment: Note that $$\Gamma (\alpha)=\int ^\infty_0 e^{-t} t^{\alpha-1} dt$$

Comment: So I got $\frac{\lambda^{\alpha}}{\Gamma (\alpha)}*\frac{\Gamma(\alpha +1)}{\alpha+1}$

How should I continue?

Comment: I think Harry's answer should clear your doubts.

Comment: Very similar to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506963/help-with-proof-of-expected-value-of-gamma-distribution).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let us consider a random variable with Gamma distribution $X\sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha,\lambda)$. Its expected value is
\begin{equation}
E(X) = \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha} \, e^{-\lambda x} \, dx \, .
\end{equation}
Making the change of variable $y=\lambda x$ in the integral, one has
\begin{aligned}
E(X) &= \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{y}{\lambda}\right)^{\alpha} \, e^{-y} \, \frac{dy}{\lambda} \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty y^{\alpha} \, e^{-y} \, dy\\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\lambda\Gamma(\alpha)} \, .
\end{aligned}
Due to the relationship $\Gamma(\alpha+1) = \alpha\Gamma(\alpha)$, one obtains $E(X) = \alpha/\lambda$.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that when you set $y=\lambda x$ that you implicitly set $dy=\lambda dx$ which means that $dx=dy / \lambda$?

Comment: @FrankShmrank Yes, correct.