# What is the E(Y) and Var(Y) given that X is a r.v. ~ Poisson with mean Y, and Y is a r.v. ~ Gamma(alpha, beta)

Tags: statistics

Suppose X is a random variable X ~ Poisson with mean Y, and Y is a random variable ~ Gamma $(\alpha, \beta)$. Find EY and VarY

For EY and VarY this is what I have:
\begin{align*} 
f(y|\alpha,\beta) &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}}y^{\alpha-1}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}} \\
E(Y) &= \int_0^\infty y^n \frac{1} \\
{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}}y^{\alpha-1}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}} dy
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}}\int_0^\infty y^{\alpha+n-1}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}}dy = \frac{1} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*} 
{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}}\int_0^\infty (\beta t)^{\alpha+n-1}e^t\beta dt$ **$t &=\frac{y}{\beta}, \frac{dy}{\beta}=dt** \\
&=\frac{\beta^{\alpha+n}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}}\int_0^\infty \\
t^{\alpha+n-1}e^{-t}dt &= \frac{\beta^n}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha+n-1}e^{-t}dt = \frac{\beta^n \Gamma(\alpha+n)}{\Gamma^{\alpha}} ** n_1 and n_2 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
E(Y) = \frac{\beta \Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} = \alpha\beta \\
E(Y^2) &= \frac{\beta^2 \Gamma(\alpha + 2}{\Gamma(\alpha)}= \beta^2(\alpha + 1) \alpha \\
Var(Y) &= (\alpha+1)\alpha\beta^2 - \alpha^2 \beta^2 = \alpha\beta^2
\end{align*}
Please tell if this is correct or tips for what am I missing. Thank you.

Comment: Re-edit your question for improving readability.

Comment: Thank you Bob!!

Comment: @user3700604 I made some edits to improve readability. However, I am concerned that I may have changed the meaning of what you wrote. Please carefully review my changes and verfiy that what is there is what you want.

Comment: @user3700604 I do not understand what you mean by **

Comment: The connection between $X$ and $Y$ seems irrelevant. So you simple want the mean and variance  of a Gamma distribution?  The answer can be found here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189317/mean-of-gamma-distribution

Comment: Thank you @bayes2021 that is what I needed to know

Comment: Thank you @Bob I think it is understood, I need to practice latex